# How can I change an image embedded in our main Sharepoint 2007 template?

Tags: 2007

In our main Sharepoint 2007 template there is an image at the top of the page that I'd like to change. However, I'm not a Sharepoint developer so I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Can somebody please provide some instruction as to how I can go about changing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide us with a screenshot so we can see what image you're referring to, and where it is? It might give us clues as to the best way for you to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the straight out of the box templates, like a team site or blank site, go to Site Actions, Edit Page and you'll see that the image is in an Image Web part.  Simply select Edit from the web part options and select Modify Settings.  A screen will come up that you can change the URL to a different one, or provide it the URL to an existing image in the site.

If it's a custom designed template from someone else in your environment, your options for editing the picture might be different.

Comment: It is a custom designed template made by a consultant before I worked here. I've opened the master page in SP Designer 2007 but am trying to figure things out.

Comment: Since it was created by someone else, it's hard telling what they've done.  It could be something as simple as changing a URL in an image web part or a link in a CSS file, or something complex like it being programmatically created on deployment of the template.  Screenshots will be helpful.

Comment: I've figured it out and have run into a different problem now. I'll go ahead and award you the answer though since for a user with a standard template would have been able to use that answer.